# Terminal highlight color changes when window is not targeted

Tags: terminal, color

I have a terminal profile in which I changed the highlight color (let's say, to green). I didn't like it so I changed it back to blue. Now, whenever I am targeting the window and I highlight, the highlight color is blue, but if I click on another window (the terminal is now a background window), then the highlighted portion turns back to green.

How can I change the highlight color so that it stays the same as when the window is targeted?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my terminal configuration file. 
The highlight color is Blue and is not changing to any other color when in the background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ANSIBrightGreenColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OVU5TUkdCXE5TQ29sb3JTcGFjZVYkY2xhc3NPECcw
    LjEwNTU1NTYxOTIgMC44Mzk3MTYzNzIzIDAuMDI1MzAxMTM3MgAQAYAC0hAREhNaJGNs
    YXNzbmFtZVgkY2xhc3Nlc1dOU0NvbG9yohIUWE5TT2JqZWN0XxAPTlNLZXllZEFyY2hp
    dmVy0RcYVHJvb3SAAQgRGiMtMjc7QUhOW2KMjpCVoKmxtL3P0tcAAAAAAAABAQAAAAAA
    AAAZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA2Q==
    </data>
    <key>BackgroundAlphaInactive</key>
    <real>0.45274769176136365</real>
    <key>BackgroundBlur</key>
    <real>0.04529918323863636</real>
    <key>BackgroundColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OVU5TUkdCXE5TQ29sb3JTcGFjZVYkY2xhc3NPEC8w
    LjA1OTE4MTQxNTkzIDAuMDU5MTgxNDE1OTMgMC4wNTkxODE0MTU5MyAwLjc4ABABgALS
    EBESE1okY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFzc2VzV05TQ29sb3KiEhRYTlNPYmplY3RfEA9OU0tl
    eWVkQXJjaGl2ZXLRFxhUcm9vdIABCBEaIy0yNztBSE5bYpSWmJ2osbm8xdfa3wAAAAAA
    AAEBAAAAAAAAABkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADh
    </data>
    <key>BackgroundSettingsForInactiveWindows</key>
    <false/>
    <key>CursorBlink</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Font</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGGBlYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKQHCBESVSRudWxs1AkKCwwNDg8QVk5TU2l6ZVhOU2ZGbGFnc1ZOU05hbWVWJGNs
    YXNzI0AoAAAAAAAAEBCAAoADWkFuZGFsZU1vbm/SExQVFlokY2xhc3NuYW1lWCRjbGFz
    c2VzVk5TRm9udKIVF1hOU09iamVjdF8QD05TS2V5ZWRBcmNoaXZlctEaG1Ryb290gAEI
    ERojLTI3PEJLUltiaXJ0dniDiJOco6avwcTJAAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAHAAAAAAAAAAA
    AAAAAAAAAMs=
    </data>
    <key>FontAntialias</key>
    <true/>
    <key>FontWidthSpacing</key>
    <real>1.0030539772727272</real>
    <key>Linewrap</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProfileCurrentVersion</key>
    <real>2.04</real>
    <key>TextBoldColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OVU5TUkdCXE5TQ29sb3JTcGFjZVYkY2xhc3NGMCAx
    IDEAEAGAAtIQERITWiRjbGFzc25hbWVYJGNsYXNzZXNXTlNDb2xvcqISFFhOU09iamVj
    dF8QD05TS2V5ZWRBcmNoaXZlctEXGFRyb290gAEIERojLTI3O0FITltiaWttcn2GjpGa
    rK+0AAAAAAAAAQEAAAAAAAAAGQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALY=
    </data>
    <key>TextColor</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDUAQIDBAUGFRZYJHZlcnNpb25YJG9iamVjdHNZJGFyY2hpdmVyVCR0b3AS
    AAGGoKMHCA9VJG51bGzTCQoLDA0OVU5TUkdCXE5TQ29sb3JTcGFjZVYkY2xhc3NPECcw
    LjQ0OTY2MTY2NjggMC43MjAwNDA1MTk1IDAuODg5OTk5OTg1NwAQAYAC0hAREhNaJGNs
    YXNzbmFtZVgkY2xhc3Nlc1dOU0NvbG9yohIUWE5TT2JqZWN0XxAPTlNLZXllZEFyY2hp
    dmVy0RcYVHJvb3SAAQgRGiMtMjc7QUhOW2KMjpCVoKmxtL3P0tcAAAAAAAABAQAAAAAA
    AAAZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA2Q==
    </data>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Basic</string>
    <key>type</key>
    <string>Window Settings</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Download the file from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8kcy9by1yvtz9r4/Basic.terminal?dl=0).

Comment: Can you please copy contents of file directly and/or copy only pertinent pieces?

Comment: @Laurbert515 please check.

Comment: I used your method and the highlight color does actually change when I click on another window. It turns to a lighter color.

Comment: Try  this, Preference > Profile > Windows Tab > in Backgrounds option > click Color & Effects > uncheck Inactive Windows.

Comment: Inactive Windows is already unchecked!